# Distributed Database Solution?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, load-balancing

Hey. I am going to be setting up a a database which could get really really huge.

I've been using standard mysql for most of my stuff but this particular problem will get up to the TBs and I will want to be able to do hundreds of queries a second.

So aside from designing my database schema such that its not going to chug, and fast harddrive speeds what is my biggest bottleneck and what sort of solution is recommended for this.

Does it make sense to spread the database over multiple computers on my intranet so it can scale with CPU/Ram etc and if so is there software for this or database solutions for this?

Thanks for any help!
I did a search for questions to related to this and couldn't find anything so sorry if it has already been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database scalability is a VERY complicated issue; there are a LOT of issues that come into the whole process.

First, consider the lowest-hanging fruit; do you have individual tables (or columns) that are going to be containing the bulk of your data?  Columns which will contain BLOBs which are > 4MB each?  Those can be extracted from the database and stored on a flat-file storage system, and merely referred to from the database; right there, that can take many unwieldy solutions down to a manageable level.

If not, do you have deeply different usage patterns for different subgroupings of tables?  If so, there's an opportunity right there for segmenting your database into different functional databases which can be partitioned onto different servers.  A good example of this is read-mostly data, such as on webservers, which gets generated rarely (think user-specific home page data), but read frequently; that type of data can get segregated into a database (or, again, flatfile with references) that's separate from the rest of the user data).

Consider the transactional requirements of your database; can you isolate your transaction boundaries cleanly, or will there be deeply mingled transactions going on all through your database?  If you can isolate your transaction boundaries, there's another potential useful boundary.

This is just touching on some of the issues involved with this sort of thing.  One thing worth considering is whether or not you really need to have a database that is actually going to be huge, or if you're just trying to use the database as a persistence layer.  If you're using the database just as a persistence layer, you might reconsider whether you actually need the relational nature of a database at all, or if you can get away with a smaller relational overlay on top of a simpler persistence layer.  (I say this because a large quantity of solutions seem like they could get away with a thin relational layer over a large persistence layer; it's worth considering.)

Comment: to give you a little more info on the actual problem at hand, we are going to be extracting large amounts of data from a bunch of sources and parsing tons of statistics from each entry. every day the database will deal with 100,000+ new entries each with 100's of statistics. the actual file size of each entry is prob < 1KB and once its parsed doesn't need to be used. we will then run lots and lots of different queries in real time on the every growing dataset and eventually open up the platform for other people to do the same.

Comment: @nextgenneo:  yeah, you DO have a bit of a problem there.  I'd still recommend doing what you can to sensibly partition your database; is there some sort of temporal horizon across which you won't be crossing, or the like?  Because if you really do have a large, unpartitionable relational dataset, you may need to end up going with a (very expensive) commercial solution.  I'm no fan of Oracle (to say the least), but they understand epic scaling better than anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first I need to point you to **[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296500/what-db-for-big-databases)**  I don't think MySQL is going to perform like you want.  I have a bad feeling that when I say you need to look into an Oracle instalation, you're going to say, "We don't have the cash for that."  But, when I say get the latest/greatest SQL-Server, you're going to say, "We don't have the hardware it'll take to implement that."  I'm afraid that terabytes is just flat out going to crush your MySQL instalation.

Comment: Given his clarification in the comment to my answer above, I feel you might be right; and your point about Oracle is exactly right.  Oracle serves very well as a cash sink, and once you're with them, there's no turning back; that said, they're really the only game in town when it comes to the type of scalability they specialize in...

Answer (score 0):

A new breed of NewSQL databases are being built to solve exactly the problem of distributing resources over multiple servers. The [Clustrix](http://www.clustrix.com) database (which was built from the ground up to be a MySQL replacement) is one example that provides near-linear scale -- as you run out of CPU/Memory, you can simple add nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Database scalability is a tough problem and you should consider solutions that can address it for you. I believe that MySQL can be used as the foundation for a solution to your problem.

Horizontal scalability; the ability to scale a database horizontally (aka scale-out) is a good technique to address the problem of very large tables and databases.